# Time series with an order of integration greater than 1

Tags: time-series, unit-root

The issue of unit roots and what $ I(1) $ variables do to a regression estimation is covered clearly online. However, it is of course possible to have order of integration greater than 1. What does it actually mean to say a time series is $ I(n) $ where $n>1$ ? What would a series like this look like? Are there any examples of series we would expect to display this property? Does it present any further problems than an $ I(1) $ variable?